# Get textbox text

Tags: php, html

When I click the button the text from the textbox should be written to a `.txt` file, which then should be downloaded. Somehow the `isset` function doesn't work, I already tried to link the php file with a `<form`>, but then I can't read the textbox text.

Here's my code:

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    print ($text);

    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $string = $text;

    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
    header('Content-type: application/txt');
    readfile('test.txt');
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Editor</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
        <p>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Download Text</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to have a `<form>` tag to be able to submit your data:

```
<body>
<form action="add your php filename here" method="post">

...

</form>
</body>
```

You might also need to make your `<button type="submit"` into `<input type="submit"`

Comment: thanks! I already tried the <form> tag before, but without the method post, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Add a form tag and post back to same page if php document is within the same file.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    print ($text);

    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $string = $text;

    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
    header('Content-type: application/txt');
    readfile('test.txt');
 }?> 

<html>
<head>
  <title>Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea><p>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">Download Text</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the form TaG in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In your current HTML, you need a `<form>` tag.

Try reading about this [here.](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)

Comment: Why can't you have PHP in the same file as the form, if it's posting back to itself?

Comment: You can specify any file you as the action - leaving it out defaults to using the same file, in fact. The only time you're going to have issues is if your form is a plain HTML file, I think.

Comment: Cool!  Well, I learned something new.  Removed incorrect info.